# Is there a better way for finding bound of an object array?

Tags: java

I have a check to find the bound of a object array:

```
static int findLength(Change[] ma) {
        int i=0;
        boolean cont = true;
        try {
            while(true) {
                ma[i].getCoin();
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Hit bound at " + i + " e");
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Currently using a catch, but i feel this may be a bad way to break the program on purpose. Is there a better way to find the bound? I did kind of dig myself a whole in how i setup my array to get to this point, but knowing a better method for this could still be helpful to know.

Comment: Do you mean `ma.length`? Or something like `if(ma[i] == null)` if you define "boundary" as "how many actual elements are in there"?

Comment: I also don't understand what the "bound" is here.  It's not a concept I've seen in Java before.

Comment: What do you mean by 'bound'? What is Change? What Exceptions do you expect beeing thrown from getCoin()?
Or are you just checking for null (NullPointerException)?

Comment: They're obviously also checking for `IndexOutOfBound` exception, but this is a terrible way to do it.

Comment: i was just looking for .length, though it was working for some reason and keeping my original value of 20. Sorry wasted long time on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace a call to your method by this:

```
int i=yourArray.length;
```

Comment: this was all i needed... brain too tired just changed it thx

Answer (score 0):

In case you are just looking for the array length: The solution is `ma.length`, as pointed out in the first comment, from Thomas.
If you try to find the first array item that is null - here is an example of the way I would solve it:

```
    int i = 0;
    for (String elm : ma) {
        if (elm == null) break;
        ++i;
    }
    
    System.out.println("bound = " + i);
```